# Django: Check if Model Fields are answered

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-orm

my code should give me True if all model form fields in the list have values set. If one or more form fields are not answered, it should give me False.

I have this so far:

```
fields_list = [field1, field2, field3]
if all(field != "" for field in fields_list) is True:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

This works for simple CharFields, e.g.:

```
field1 = models.CharField('Field1', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

But it does not seem to work for CharField with predefined choices:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('yes', 'yes'),
    ('no', 'no'),
)
field2 = models.CharField('Field2', choices=CHOICES, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

And it does not seem to work for DateFields etc.

Can anybody help me to find out how to check this for all kinds of model form fields?

Comment: Just make all form field as `required`, the form will not be valid until user fill all form fields. By default all form fields are required if you didn't make them optional by setting `null=True` or `blank=True`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is not possible to require all form fields. The user should be able to save forms with missing fields. What I'm trying to do is to show a "TODO" if there are missing entries and "DONE" if all fields are filled in.

Answer (score 2):

While the OP's answer is headed in the right direction, I needed to adjust it a little bit for it to work properly and to consider all the fields in my model without having to list them manually. Here's what I've come up with:

```
class MyModel(models.model)
    # long list of fields here..

    def is_fully_filled(self):
        ''' Checks if all the fields have been filled '''
        fields_names = [f.name for f in self._meta.get_fields()]

        for field_name in fields_names:
            value = getattr(self, field_name)
            if value is None or value == '':
                return False

        return True
```

If you need to store this value in the database as a computed property (which will be updated automatically every time you change a field in the list), it can be easily done with [django-computed-property](https://github.com/brechin/django-computed-property):

```
class MyModel(models.model)
    # long list of fields here..
    fully_filled = computed_property.ComputedBooleanField(
        compute_from='is_fully_filled', default=False)

    def is_fully_filled(self):
        ''' Checks if all the fields have been filled '''
        fields_names = [f.name for f in self._meta.get_fields()]

        for field_name in fields_names:
            if field_name == 'fully_filled':
                continue # avoid recursive calls to is_fully_filled

            value = getattr(self, field_name)
            if value is None or value == '':
                return False

        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of things. In the end this simple solution seems to work:

```
fields_list = [field1, field2, field3]
if any(field is None or field == '' for field in fields_list) is True:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Comment: This answer _may_ be correct, but it still requires the developer to list all the fields included in the model. If you want to automatically check all the fields in a model, check out my answer!